# How better to create Users table?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I created `Users` table.
After the user registered, The system enter his address, phone, city and more personal details to `Users` table.
There is another table, called `Contacts`, there the user add another people details.

Now, if there is `Contacts` table, How better to save the personal details of the user in `Users` table? in one json column that contains all the user personal details, or in normal columns (address, phone, city)?

I just do not want to happen a situation of multiple data.

Comment: What you are asking about seems to be [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). What is the difference between `User` and `Contact`? Which fields are the same?

Comment: @feeela No, I just want to know if to create json field that contains all personal details in `Users` table, or to create normal columns (address, phone, city) in the table instead one json column that contains all the personal details.

Answer (score 1):

I think separate columns for each field will be the better option!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would of course be easy to just store it as `JSON`, but that way, it could be a bit messy to search for certain stuff in the database (say you wish to check all users from a given city for example).
When it comes to user information, I always find the best way to do this is to store only login vital data and the base info in a `users` table.

Something like:

```
id | email | password
```

And then have different tables for the other data.

Name and such (which a user only has one of (of course one could have multiple names, but I usually only store first and last names)) could be stored in a `user_information` table, which is in a one to one relation with the user (foreign key for the `user_id` so that it can be quickly fetched when needed).

When it comes to address and phone number, a user could actually have multiple.
I understand that its possible that your system/app is only supposed to support one address or one phone number and the like, but its always nice to make it "right" from the start, so that its easy to just let the user add multiple of them whenever the need is there.

That way, you would have a few different tables:

- `users`
- `user_information`
- `addresses`
- `phone_numbers`
- and so on...

The `user_information`, `addresses` and `phone_numbers` would preferably all have a `user_id` column which would be used for a foreign key to point at the user who owns it. And if you wish to make it possible to use the same tables for contacts, a `contact_id` could be added too (and a foreign key to point to the contact).